# ldap searchtype substring not working when value is an integer is less than one thousand

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ldap, ldap-query

I search and users from active directory. My code is below:

```
List<DirectoryEntry> dirEntries = ActiveDirectoryActions.getListByQuery("(&(objectClass=user)(displayName~=*" + q + "*))");
            for (int i = 0; i < dirEntries.Count; i++)
            {
                SiteSearchResult r = new SiteSearchResult();
                r.title = dirEntries[i].Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
                r.url = "/" + lang + "/directory/user/" + dirEntries[i].Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();
                r.content = dirEntries[i].Properties["title"].Value.ToString();
                result.Add(r);
            }
```

And it is getListByQuery() function

```
public static List<DirectoryEntry> getListByQuery(string q)
        {

            DirectorySearcher drSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);
            drSearch.Filter = "(distinguishedName=" + Config.xml().Root.Elements("active_directory").Elements("root_ou").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().ToString() + ")";
            DirectoryEntry searchRoot = drSearch.FindAll()[0].GetDirectoryEntry();
            drSearch.SearchRoot = searchRoot;

            drSearch.Filter = q;
            List<DirectoryEntry> r = new List<DirectoryEntry>();
            SearchResultCollection sr = drSearch.FindAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < sr.Count; i++)
            {
                r.Add(sr[i].GetDirectoryEntry());
            }

            return r;

        }
```

Everthing is ok on my local server. But gives error on global server when I search integer value. And that is interesting when the value less than 1000 (<1000) .

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    Myproject.Controllers.SearchController.Index(String
>   lang, String q) in
>   D:\dotNET\Myproject\Myproject\Controllers\SearchController.cs:60

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are few issues you need to check

1) Does it make sense to call DirectoryEntry.FindAll() two times? Instead of using DirectorySearcher(rootEntry) you could try to set

```
string ldapPath = "LDAP://" + Config.xml().Root.Elements("active_directory").Elements("root_ou").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath);
DirectorySearcher desearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
deSearch.Filter = ...
```

2) Approximate search `~=` might be not compatible with a substring search (`=*substring*`), e.g. for me it does not work. So try to change to `=*1000*` (without ~)

3) FindAll() in both cases could return null, so you should check for null in both cases.

4) [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall(v=vs.110).aspx)]

> Due to implementation restrictions, the SearchResultCollection class
>   cannot release all of its unmanaged resources when it is garbage
>   collected. To prevent a memory leak, you must call the Dispose method
>   when the SearchResultCollection object is no longer needed.

So you either need to call sr.Dispose or use a using Statement.